# What am I missing? If statement executing when it evaluates to false

Tags: java

```
while (currentNode != null) {

   Letter currentLetter = currentNode.getElement();

   if (currentLetter.decorator() != "!") {

      return false;

   }

   currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

}

return true;
```

In the attached picture, you can see currentLetter.decorator() = "!",
so the if statement should evaluate to false, but the method returns
false immediately, meaning the if branch somehow executed. This really shouldn't be
that difficult, I must be missing something small because I have no idea why this is
happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51EeT.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use `.equals()` (or its inversion) to compare strings in Java not `==` or `!=` . Otherwise you are comparing the instances of the String (whether they are the same object), not the String contents (whether they have the same value).

For details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839).